# FineUploader constructor is failing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, fine-uploader

I have some FineUploader code that is nearly identical to the dev's demo code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/fineuploader/fineuploader-3.5.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
      alert("A");
      var manualuploader = new qq.FineUploader({
         element: $('#manual-fine-uploader')[0],
         request: {
            endpoint: 'server/handleUploads'
         },
         autoUpload: false,
         text: {
            uploadButton: '<i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> Select Files'
         }
      });
      alert("B");
      $('#triggerUpload').click(function () {
         manualuploader.uploadStoredFiles();
      });
      alert("C");
   });
</script>
```

I've been having problems getting this control to work, so I threw those alerts in there just to see if the FineUploader init code was completing.  As it happens, After the "A" alert is displayed, no other alerts are.  This seems to indicate that the `qq.FineUploader(...)` call is hanging.  I've rechecked the fineuploader js path several times and it's correct.

If I wrap the problem area in try/catch the exception states that "ReferenceError: qq is not defined."  It's defined in the fineuploader js, and IntelliSense recognizes it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error suggests that the path to fineuploader.js is indeed not correct.  Check that the library has actually been imported.  If you are using Chrome, you can do so by looking at the sources tab in the developer console, and checking to see if the js file appears there.  Perhaps there are other errors in the javascript console that will provide more clues as well.

Comment: You're completely correct.  Visual Studio was telling me that the path was correct, but in the js dev console, I could see it had a partial path prepended, so the js was not loading.  After fixing this, the control renders (kind of, still need to figure out styling).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Okay i found the problem, so make sure the fineuploader js file is before the scripts. my mistake was that i put all the script code first and at the end had the library link.